# Gesture Recognizer go to detail

Tags: xamarin

i have a page with Cards and once i tap on one i need to get detailed data. I have Gesture recognizer so i am able to navigate to he second page but with no details.
 I have tried to add TapGesture in xaml but it didnt work.

```
This is my xaml 
                            <grial:Repeater
                        Padding="0"
                        ItemsSource="{ Binding ListOfBestSellers }"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        Spacing="0"

                        VerticalOptions="End"
                        ScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                                <grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <local:AvatArticleBrowserCardItemTemplate
                                Padding="10,0,5,5"
                                WidthRequest="150" >
                                    </local:AvatArticleBrowserCardItemTemplate>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
                            </grial:Repeater>

and Template 

<ContentView.Content>
        <grial:CardView 
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            CornerRadius="5" x:Name="articleCard">

            <grial:CardView.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="Auto" />
            </grial:CardView.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- ARTICLE IMAGE -->
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="-14,0,-14,10"
                Source="{ Binding BackgroundImage }"
                Aspect="AspectFill" />

            <Grid
                Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                RowSpacing="10"
                Padding="14,10">

                <!-- TITLE -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Text="{ Binding Title }"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Style="{ StaticResource LabelBoldStyle }"
                    TextColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }" />

                <!-- CATEGORY -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Text="{ Binding Section }"
                    FontSize="12"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" />

                <!--  DATE -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Text="{ Binding When }"
                    FontSize="12"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalOptions="End" />

            </Grid>
        </grial:CardView>
    </ContentView.Content>

This is what i have

async void GoToCardDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyArticle());
            }
            else
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
            }

        }
        private void CardDetail()
        {
            articleCard.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
            TapGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizerArticleDetail = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            gestureRecognizerArticleDetail.Tapped += GoToCardDetail;
            articleCard.GestureRecognizers.Add(gestureRecognizerArticleDetail);

        }

But its not giving me detailed data, on my list view from other page i have this 
private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
#if !NAVIGATION
            var selectedItem = ((ListView) sender).SelectedItem;
            var articlePage = new MyArticle(selectedItem as ArticleDetailData);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(articlePage);
#endif

        }
```

my MyArticle const

```
public MyArticles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MyArticlesListViewModel(null);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="articles"></param>
        /// <param name="categoryName"></param>
        public MyArticles(List<Article> articles, string categoryName)
        {
            _categoryName = categoryName;
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MyArticlesListViewModel(articles);



        }
```

And that works perfectly can zou please help me how to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the selected item to `MyArticle`'s constructor

```
var card = (CardView) sender;
var item = (ArticleDetailData)card.BindingContext;
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyArticle(item));
```

Comment: I addded const of myarticle to the post. I have tried your solution but i cant access binding context

Comment: you will also need to cast sender to the correct type first.  Based on your code I'm not quite sure what that is - you may need to check the type in the debugger

Comment: sender is cardview

Comment: well, then cast sender to CardView